# Adding a Scroll to Next Element With the Same Class in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, jquery-animate

I am trying to add functionality of an arrow when clicked would scroll the user to the next section with a specified class. Each section would have the same class and an arrow with a class to target in jQuery. So I will have a few sections set up like this:

```
<section class="homeSection">
   <div class="content">
     //Content goes here
   </div>
   <div class="btnContainer">
    <button class="arrow">Arrow</button>
   </div>
</section>

<section class="homeSection">
   <div class="content">
     //Content goes here
   </div>
   <div class="btnContainer">
    <button class="arrow">Arrow</button>
   </div>
</section>

<section class="homeSection">
   <div class="content">
     //Content goes here
   </div>
   <div class="btnContainer">
    <button class="arrow">Arrow</button>
   </div>
</section>

//And so on...
```

So there will be around 5 sections set up with this setup with the same classes for the section and the button. What I am trying to do then is when the button of a section is clicked it will then scroll to the very next section below it and that cycle will continue until you reach the last section and the end of the page.

I at first had it set up like so:

```
    $(".downArrow--hero").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(".cardItems").offset().top
     }, 1000);
     });
```

And it would target each section based on a unique class, but I now need to set it up with each section having the same class. What would be my best approach to this?

Comment: You could use something like `$(this).parents(".homeSection").next(".homeSection")`

Comment: @Titus I tried setting it up like so:  `$("downArrow").click(function() {
   $('html, body').animate({
       scrollTop: $(this).parents(".homeSection").next(".homeSection").offset().top
   }, 1000);
 });`     But that didn't seem to work. It wasn't throwing any errors, but it wasn't functioning either.

Comment: It should be `$(".downArrow")` instead of `$("downArrow")` (with a dot before the class name).

Comment: It seems to work https://jsbin.com/xilagozoci/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: @Titus Whoops I should of saw that, but after I add the dot for the class I now get an error about the '.top' part of the function saying it is undefined

Comment: That is because `$(this).parents(".homeSection").next(".homeSection")` doesn't match any elements, you'll have to change the classes in there (`homeSection`) to match your layout.